# Miscellaneous and Inter-Thread Communication Instructions in CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia, profiler, instructions

I've been playing around with the NVIDIA profiler (nvprof) and there are two particular metrics which I do not understand:

```
inst_inter_thread_communication
    Number of inter-thread communication instructions executed by non-predicated threads
inst_misc
    Number of miscellaneous instructions executed by non-predicated threads
```

I'm just wondering what instructions would be inter-thread communication instructions and which instructions would fall under miscellaneous.

Reference:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#metrics-reference

Comment: Inter thread communication would be shuffle functions, http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#warp-shuffle-functions and possibly thread sync functions or memory fence functions. Misc is anything not covered by the other set of recorded instructions. I'm not entirely sure, but I presume they could along the lines of char operations, comparison operations, loop overhead, special function operations, overhead for device functions, in kernel memory malloc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SASS instructions that fall into the two categories are as follows:

**inst_inter_thread_communication**

- SHFL
- VOTE

**inst_misc**

- NOP
- S2R, B2R, R2B, P2R
- LEPC
- CSET[P], PSET[P]
- MOV
- SEL
- PRMT
- Maxwell Only (BAR, DEPBAR)
- *There are several infrequent undocumented instructions that increment this category.*

The document **CUDA Binary Utilities** section [**Instruction Set Reference**](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#instruction-set-ref) contains a brief description of the SASS instructions. There is close to a 1:1 relationship between SASS and PTX so you can also review the [**PTX ISA**](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#axzz3PDimGbXg) manual.